# Как вызвать функцию JS после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

В функции необходимо повесить евент на элемент input. Если есть какие-то предложения пишите

Comment: Заголовок и тело явно некоррелируют между собой

Answer (score 0):

например так

```js
window.onload = function yourFunc(){
  alert("Page done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fun(){
console.log('run fun');
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fun);
```